# Microsoft Excel Application (DCOM)

Tags: c#, asp.net, interop, dcom

My Web Application is writing an Excel file, using Interop.Excel. I already changed the security and identity of Microsoft Excel Application on DCOM and it works fine for about 4/6/8 hours, then the following error message appears:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following
>   error: 8000401a.

Identity: interactive user.
Security contains "INTERACTIVE", "NETWORK SERVICE" and all of domain users with full rights.

I've already tried everything that Google advises.

Thanks!

Comment: You clearly didn't try everything, because if you Googled everything you would have eventually come across [Considerations for server-side Office Automation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757) which basically states that you should never use Office Interop in a server environment. And if you do, you're likely to get strange errors. There are plenty of workarounds, I discuss some of them on my [blog](https://masonmcg.com/blog/entry/properly-generating-excel-files-in-net).

Comment: useless links, the question is security approach to Microsoft Excel Application

Comment: I happen to think the fact that you're doing something completely unsupported would be a good reason to suggest an alternative approach. I'm sorry you disagree.